# Why I can't automatically list all the branches of a cloned repository?

Tags: git, github

I am not so into GIT and I am finding the following problem using GIT on my Ubuntu machine.

I clone this repository from GitHub: https://github.com/angular-university/reactive-angular-course/tree/1-start

Then I entered into the cloned project directory. Now I want to see the list of all the branches so I perforemd this command:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Angular-WS/reactive-angular-course$ git branch
* master
```

As you can see it list only the **master** branch but the GIT project contains also other branches (as you can see on the previous GitHub page).

The strange thing is that I can checkout another branch by:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Angular-WS/reactive-angular-course$ git checkout 1-start
Branch '1-start' set up to track remote branch '1-start' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch '1-start'
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Angular-WS/reactive-angular-course$ git branch
* 1-start
  master
```

And, as you can see, after the checkout the selected branch appear (as active one) performing again **git branch** command.

Why this behavior? I expected that performing **git branch** command for the first time it lists all the branches related to this repository.

What am I missing?

Comment: `git branch` lists only local branches by default. You can use `git branch --all` to list local and remote branches.

Comment: You need to read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch,  option `-a` is used to list both remote-tracking branches and local branches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloning a repository copies *all* <sup>1</sup> of its commits, and *none* of its branches.<sup>2</sup>  You don't need branches to have commits.<sup>3</sup>

After the clone is finished but before returning you to a shell prompt, `git clone` runs one `git checkout`; this one `git checkout` creates one branch.  You can go on to create more branches, or—at least for some purposes—just use the names that `git clone` created, which aren't *branch names*, but are perfectly good names.

The names that `git clone` creates are *remote-tracking names*.  If the remote named `origin` had branches named `main`, `feature/tall`, and `feature/short`, the clone has names `origin/main`, `origin/feature/tall`, and `origin/feature/short`.

The final `git checkout` step takes one of those names and uses it to create a branch name.<sup>4</sup>  The name chosen here is from your [`-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--bltnamegt) parameter to `git clone`.  If you didn't give a `-b` parameter here, your Git asks the other Git, during the clone process, which name *it* recommends, and uses that one.

These remote-tracking names show up in `git branch -r` output.  They're not actually *branch* names, they were just created *from* branch names, but if all you need is the name, they'll do the job.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically it copies only the *reachable* commits.  But you can't find the unreachable ones, so you can't tell that it didn't copy them.

<sup>2</sup>A so-called *mirror clone* does copy all of its branches.  You cannot do any new work in a mirror clone, though.

<sup>3</sup>You do need *names* to *find* the commits, but they need not be branch names.

Curiously, the converse *is* true: you *must* have at least one commit to have any branch names.  In fact, you must have at least one commit or other internal Git object in order to have any name that is not a symbolic name.  (Symbolic names are those that act like `HEAD`: that hold some other name, typically a branch name.  `HEAD` is normally the only symbolic name you'll see, in part because other symbolic names don't work very well in some versions of Git.)

<sup>4</sup>This is, internally at least, called *DWIM mode*, with DWIM standing for Do What I Mean (not what I say).  That is, you asked `git checkout` to check out some branch *X* when branch *X* does not exist.  Rather than immediately giving you an error, `git checkout` pokes around through your remote-tracking names, looking for an `origin/X` for instance.  If it finds exactly one candidate that looks right, it converts your request to switch to an existing branch, into a request to create a new branch, whose branch-tip-commit is the same commit as the one identified by the remote-tracking name.

It is all very elegant and confusing.  Once you get used to it, it's pretty useful.  Then it all breaks when you add a second remote and there are now two remote-tracking names that look like good candidates.  Git has recently grown some new facilities to handle this case better, but until you understand DWIM mode in the first place, adding this on will just make things *really* confusing.

Comment: _You do need names to find the commits, but they need not be branch names_ By names other than branches, you mean like tags or just the 'remote-tracking names'?

Comment: @Honey: Yes. Tags (`v1.2`), or remote-tracking names (`origin/master`), or any other names that you might like to use or invent. Those three—branch, tag, and remote-tracking names—are the ones you'll see most, but Git has a bunch of internal ones, such as `refs/stash`, names for bisecting, temporary names created for interactive rebasing, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`git` makes a distinction between local and remote branches, and the default for `git branch` is to only list local branches.

You have to use a flag to see the other branches :

- [`git branch -r|--remotes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--r) will list remote branches only
- [`git branch -a|--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--a) will list both local and remote branches