# Why isn't git's remotes directory not showing all the fetched branches?

Tags: git

I just cloned Alamofire repo.

On the repo it has [8 branches](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/branches).

However when I go into my `Alamofire/.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory I only see HEAD.

Shouldn’t I be seeing all 8 branches? I already did a `git fetch --all`

FWIW I tried doing `git checkout hotfix` and it just worked. Implying that the branch has already been fetched. If that's the case then again I expect the branch to exist within the `Alamofire/.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory.

Comment: Related (maybe a duplicate): [Why I can't automatically list all the branches of a cloned repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64368139/1256452)

Answer (score 1):

> I expect the branch to exist within the *Alamofire/.git/refs/remotes/origin* directory

Your expectations are wrong. Try `git branch --list --all`. Now you will "see" the branches.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's expected to be seen in that directory? I just looked now and it seems that it just contains the commit hash. But if the fetched items aren't in there, then where do they go to?

Comment: The branches are listed in the _packed-refs_ file. It's a text file, so you can look and see. But don't. Basically, don't look under the hood like this. Use the tools you are given.

Comment: Also, you don't need to say `fetch --all`, it doesn't mean what you think it does. Just `fetch` will do. And in this case it wasn't necessary in the first place. You've _got all the branches_ — that is what a plain `clone` does.

Comment: (adding to matt's comment) : the `packed-refs` file is located under the `.git/` of your project : `cat Alamofire/.git/packed-refs`. Again as matt said, you're better off using git commands than inspecting by hand the internals : `git branch -a|-r` or `git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin`